# Why do I need to map IntStream to Stream<Character>

Tags: java, collections, java-8, set, java-stream

```
  public static int construction(String myString) {
      Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();

      int count = myString.chars()  // returns IntStream
      .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)       // Stream<Character> why is this required?
      .mapToInt(c -> (set.add(c) == true ? 1 : 0)) // IntStream
      .sum();

      return count;
    }
```

The above code will not compile without:

```
.mapObj(c -> (char)c)
// <Character> Stream<Character> java.util.stream.IntStream.mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends Character> mapper)
```

If i remove it, I get the following error

```
The method mapToInt((<no type> c) -> {}) is undefined for the type IntStream
```

Can someone explain this? It seems like I am starting with and IntStream, converting to a Stream of Characters and then back to IntStream.

Comment: because your set takes `Character`s

Comment: One thing that the question still lack is what is it that you were actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @naman, trying to get a count of distinct characters in a string. as pointed out below, I should have used stream distinct for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method [`CharSequence::chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) returns the [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), which of course doesn't provide any method converting to int, such as `mapToInt`, but `mapToObj` instead. Therefore the method [`IntStream::map(IntUnaryOperator mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) which both takes returns `int` as well shall be used since [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) does the same like `Function<Integer, Integer>` or `UnaryOperator<Integer>`:

```
int count = myString.chars()                 // IntStream
    .map(c -> (set.add((char) c) ? 1 : 0))   // IntStream
    .sum();

long count = myString.chars()                // IntStream
    .filter(c -> set.add((char) c))          // IntStream
    .count();
```

Also, using `Set<Integer>` helps you to avoid conversion to a Character:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
```

---

```
int count = myString.chars()                 // IntStream
    .map(c -> (set.add(c) ? 1 : 0))          // IntStream
    .sum();

long count = myString.chars()                // IntStream
    .filter(set::add)                        // IntStream
    .count();
```

---

However, regardless of what you try to achieve, your code is wrong by principle. See the [Stateless behaviors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). Consider using the following snippet which lambda expressions' results are not *dependent* on the result of a non-deterministic operation, such as `Set::add`.

> Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the behavioral parameters to the stream operations are stateful.

```
long count = myString.chars()             // IntStream
                     .distinct()          // IntStream
                     .count();
```

Comment: And for the advanced: `int count = myString.chars().collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or).cardinality();`

Comment: @nikolas, thanks for the clarifying and as pointed out using distinct() is a better choice. I have tended to ignore the Stateless requirement with non-parallel streams but that is a bad habit that needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

You can also collect to a set and then take the size without using an explicit map.
It does not require using external state to contain the characters.

```java
    long count = str.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()).size();
```

But imho, the more direct approach which was already mentioned is cleaner in appearance and the one I would prefer to use.

```java
    long count = str.chars().distinct().count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `String.chars()` is already returning an `IntStream` and `IntStream` does not have `mapToInt` `function`

You could use a filter instead then count:

```
int count = myString.chars()
      .filter(c -> set.add(c) == true)
      .count();
```

I admit that I made this so slubby last midnight!
As mentioned by the comments, here is the required fixes.

Thank you for mentioning.

```
long count = myString.chars()
          .filter(c -> set.add((char)c))
          .count();
```